# Adding new rows with SQL to an Access table with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in an Access database which looks like this (R1, R2, etc are the column names).

```
R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  R6
4   8   1   1   1   90,0680360218135
4   8   1   1   2   100
4   8   1   1   3   72,0756369473476
4   8   1   1   4   68,9391913253478
4   8   1   1   5   61,6543424488292
4   8   1   1   6   69,904486251809
4   8   1   1   7   47,0347033309303
4   8   1   1   8   76,3784417080973
4   8   1   1   9   33,3333333333333
1   8   1   1   1   74,1004658877797
1   8   1   1   2   97,7238166791886
1   8   1   1   3   82,1876261841859
1   8   1   1   4   68,1693097727754
1   8   1   1   5   67,71399360198
1   8   1   1   6   47,5141142738908
1   8   1   1   7   44,8295982097869
1   8   1   1   8   82,6223931742496
1   8   1   1   9   33,3333333333333
3   8   1   1   1   85,5250502810347
3   8   1   1   2   100
3   8   1   1   3   78,5248764773228
3   8   1   1   4   63,6806936758504
3   8   1   1   5   60,0848342976394
3   8   1   1   6   49,4890311068566
3   8   1   1   7   94,7562947232155
3   8   1   1   8   75,0063074448055
3   8   1   1   9   33,3333333333333
2   8   1   1   1   87,5227436005474
2   8   1   1   2   100
2   8   1   1   3   71,4484095690093
2   8   1   1   4   74,7733960793208
2   8   1   1   5   58,8799667344218
2   8   1   1   6   0
2   8   1   1   7   46,9028765060477
2   8   1   1   8   62,8187560467823
2   8   1   1   9   33,3319434019959
```

I want to add 9 new rows to the table that would be as follows:

1. R1 would be always 5 in all new columns
2. R2, R3 and R4 would stay the same (8, 1, 1)
3. R5 would be different in each new row (1 to 9)
4. R6 would be the average function of R6 in 4 different rows

For example, I want the first 2 rows to be

```
5   8   1   1   1   84,30...
5   8   1   1   2   99,43...
```

R6 column would have the value of Average function of R6 values where R1 is 1,2,3 and 4 for each R5 (1 to 9). In this previous row example (new row 1) the value of R6 would be (90,06 + 74,10 + 85,52 + 87,52) / 4) = 84,30.

I've tried SQL Group BY but I'm not getting any result or I'm doing it wrong.
Do you know which SQL statement would be correct to add those 9 new rows?